# How to make an xml look simpler and also to make it simple to retrieve values using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

```
  <reportParameterTestSettings>
     <Report uri="/standard/Project-Iteration-WorkItem-MultiFT">
       <ReportParameters>
         <name>WorkItemType</name>
         <name>CurrentUser</name>
         <name>SelectedDate</name>
         <name>TopIteration</name>
         <name>TopTeam</name>
         <name>ExecutionIteration</name>
         <name>ShowIteration</name>
         <name>SelectedExecutionIteration</name>
         <name>SelectedShowIteration</name>
         <name>ExecutionStartDate</name>
         <name>ShowEndDate</name>
         <name>Holiday</name>
         <name>JobRole</name>
         <name>EnabledFeature</name>
       </ReportParameters>
     </Report>
  </reportParameterTestSettings>
```

How can i make this xml such that is it doesn't have redundant tags such as name. Also this example consists of only one Report. In reality there would be more than 20 reports. I was thinking of adding all parameters as one string comma separated and then doing a split on it. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Combining values and then doing a split on them is counter to the idea behind XML. There's nothing wrong with this XML and in fact, it is quite simple already. Except that all element tags should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Yep i do agree. Thats why want to do it in a better way

Comment: There is no easier format (this is quite simple), and a simple node selection and foreach loop will retrieve the values easily.

Comment: I would use elements named `ReportParameter` with a `name` attribute. If you ask yourself, "what does the `ReportParameters` collection contain?" the answer is "report parameters"...not "names". Someday there may be more to the parameter than just a name. Of course, that's contrary to your desire to reduce the number of nodes, but generally XML should be as well-structured and expressive as is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating this file? A little confused by what you're asking but you should be able to do something like this

use XML Serialization

```
using System.XML.Serialization

public class reportParameterTestSettings
{
    [XmlElement("Report")]
    public List<ReportParameters> Report { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Uri")]
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}

public class ReportParameters
{
    public string WorkItemType { get; set; }
    public string CurrentUser { get; set; }
    ...etc ...etc
}
```

Write it to an xml file

```
reportParameterTestSettings data = new reportParameterTestSettings();
//add your items to data


XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(reportParameterTestSettings));
using (FileStream file = File.Create(@"c:\file.xml"))
{
    writer.Serialize(file, data);
}
```

Reading your xml file

```
reportParameterTestSettings data;

XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(reportParameterTestSettings));
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"c:\file.xml"))
{
     data = reader.Deserialize(file) as reportParameterTestSettings;
}
```

You should then end up with a file that looks like

```
<reportParameterTestSettings>
 <Report Uri=stuff>
   <ReportParameters>
     <WorkItemType>Stuff here</WorkItemType>
     <CurrentUser>Stuff here</CurrentUser>
       ...etc ...etc
   </ReportParameters>
 </Report>
 <Report Uri=stuff>
    <ReportParameters>
      <WorkItemType>Stuff here</WorkItemType>
      <CurrentUser>Stuff here</CurrentUser>
        ...etc ...etc
    </ReportParameters>
  </Report>
</reportParameterTestSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The newboston community has some great tutorials on xml in C#:
starting with this tutorial move on:http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=15&number=109

Answer (score 0):

I think your current structure is simple enough already. In fact it's very similar to having multiple rows in a database table.

In terms of querying your xml, I recommend looking at linq to xml http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx